# Magento Add To Cart To Cart page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using Magento CE 1.7 for a site. The theme being used has overridden the default behavior in Magento where after adding an item to the cart, the user is taken to teh cart page; with this theme, the user remains on the same product page, with a jquery layer poppping up to show that the item is added.

I'd like the user to be taken to the cart page every time they add an item to the cart. How best can I do this?

Thanks.
-TM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look @

/app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

The default `onclick` method should be `productAddToCartForm.submit(this)`. If your custom template have the same `onclick` method, then take a look at both base and your custom theme productAddToCartForm `submit()` method.

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
```

Also take a look @ Admin -> System -> Config -> Sales -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart -> After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. All i did was what you suggested about the config: Also take a look @ Admin -> System -> Config -> Sales -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart -> After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart. It was set to No, just changed it to Yes

Comment: Hi @R.S Kinfly guide this Question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591134/how-to-get-select-option-parameters-in-magento-cart-page/16594831?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you fill in return_url, like [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/296763/)? So you would get something like:

http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add?Product=76&qty=1&return_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fcheckout%2Fcart%2F

Answer (score 0):

Modify the design to not add the item to cart via javascript but rather just go to the link like magento default behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the custom modules which exist in app/code/community and/or app/code/local and try to figure out the module which might be doing this - maybe named AjaxCart or similar.
If you identified it, try deactivating it by editing the file app/etc/modules/NAME_OF_THAT_MODULE.xml and setting activated from true to false.
Then test if the regular behavior is back.