# How to Get select option parameters in Magento Cart page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a multi option in single product. How can i get all the product option parameters in cart page. please advise. cart page already loading in default.phtml page. this page call to renderer page. i am trying many ways but not working. Please Advise

i can print the configureaction() in Cart controller page

```
public function configureAction()
    {
        // Extract item and product to configure
        $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $projectid = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('projectid');      
        $quoteItem = null;
        $cart = $this->_getCart();
        if ($id) {
            $quoteItem = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($id);
        }

        if (!$quoteItem) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Quote item is not found.'));
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        try {
            $params = new Varien_Object();
            $params->setCategoryId(false);
            $params->setConfigureMode(true);
            $params->setBuyRequest($quoteItem->getBuyRequest());
print_r($params);
```

**My params list**

```
    [_data:protected] =&gt; Array
        (
            [category_id] =&gt; 
            [configure_mode] =&gt; 1
            [buy_request] =&gt; Varien_Object Object
                (
                    [_data:protected] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [id] =&gt; 689
                            [product] =&gt; 288
                            [related_product] =&gt; 
                            [super_attribute] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [143] =&gt; 65
                                    [144] =&gt; 71
                                )

                            [options] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [79] =&gt; 164
                                    [80] =&gt; 167
                                    [78] =&gt; 163
                                    [81] =&gt; 169
                                )

                            [attachment_hash] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [215] =&gt; 43f34b521ee06830bf462a4c060df869
                                )

                            [projectid] =&gt; 32
                            [qty] =&gt; 1
                            [reset_count] =&gt; 1
                            [original_qty] =&gt; 1
                        )

                    [_hasDataChanges:protected] =&gt; 1
                    [_origData:protected] =&gt; 
                    [_idFieldName:protected] =&gt; 
                    [_isDeleted:protected] =&gt; 
                    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] =&gt; Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] =&gt; Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] =&gt; 1
    [_origData:protected] =&gt; 
    [_idFieldName:protected] =&gt; 
    [_isDeleted:protected] =&gt; 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] =&gt; Array
        (
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] =&gt; Array
        (
        )

)
```

I need to get project id in default.phtml page or renderer.php page. please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it in items of quote object. For example:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    print_r($item->getOptions());
}
```

`$quote->getAllVisibleItems()` will return list of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` objects that contain informations about items in cart.

You should check `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` class for more details.

Comment: Where do you want to display these options? Magento display these options in cart page by default.

Comment: Hi @ndlinh i need to get default.phtml page or renderer.php page

Comment: As I said, Magento display these options in cart page by default. If you are using custom theme and you don't see that, the problem may be in your custom theme. You can check by change to using default theme. If default theme work, you should check `checkout.xml` layout file of your custom theme and compare with `checkout.xml` of default theme. The layout handler should be checked is `checkout_cart_index`.

Comment: Hi, did you try `echo $_item->getBuyRequest()->getProjectid()` in `checkout/cart/render/default.phtml`

Comment: Thankyou So much its working Great. How this possible because getProjectid is not in our file.

Comment: Because `buy_request` is a `Varien_Object` Object